# How to ungroup multiple IText using fabricJS version 1.7.22?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am implementing functionality of grouping and ungrouping.

my grouping and UnGrouping work properly for images. but when I select multiple IText using mouse and group it.

grouping is perform very well but when I UnGroup that group, at that time,

my all IText being transparent. we can select that IText, but only blank box.

```
fiddle linked below for generate issue :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/71g6enkd/

To reProduce issue, steps are is in the fiddle.

Is there any patch available for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [group#destroy](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#destroy).

***DEMO***

```js
var grp = document.getElementById('grp')
var ungrp = document.getElementById('ungrp')
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c);
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.IText('this is test', {
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  fontSize: 40
});
canvas.add(text);

var text1 = new fabric.IText('this is test', {
  top: 150,
  left: 150,
  fill: 'red',
  fontSize: 20
});
canvas.add(text1);

grp.addEventListener('click', makeGroup);
ungrp.addEventListener('click', makeUngroup);

function makeGroup() {
  console.log('make group call');
  if (!canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
    return;
  }
  var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup() || canvas.getActiveObject();
  var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();
  activegroup.clone(function(newgroup) {
    canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
    objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
      canvas.remove(object);
    });
    canvas.add(newgroup);
  });
}

function makeUngroup() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (activeObject && activeObject.type == "group") {
    var items = activeObject.getObjects();
    activeObject.destroy();
    canvas.remove(activeObject);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      canvas.add(items[i]);
    }
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.js"></script>
<button id="grp">
Make Group
</button>
<button id="ungrp">
Make UnGroup
</button>
<canvas id="c" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. this solution is really good and work for me.